# Automatically generating clientId and clientSecret from the command line

Tags: sharepoint-online

A little background: I often need to set up multiple environments (test, acceptance, production) of SharePoint Online sites. In order to keep TAP aligned, I prefer to do it with scripts. Currently, I managed to achieve a lot with the `m365 spo` command line tool (virtual kudos to anyone involved: it is absolutely awesome!). Thanks to the tool, I can:

- create the site;
- create and seed various lists;
- create content types;
- add, deploy, and install custom webpart applications.

In short, *almost* everything.

What I cannot do yet, is the registration of a new application (clientId and clientSecret) and the subsequent assignment of permissions to the application I just created. When done manually, this requires visiting the (famous?) `appregnew.aspx` and `appinv.aspx`.

Is it possible to do this via the `m365 spo` tool, of something similar that can run from a Linux box?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@Giuseppe Maggiore,

You can use below cmdlets to register an app including clientId/clientSecret:

```
$ClientId = "7680bd81-aad6-414c-a76e-cc3a06d86606"

$bytes = New-Object Byte[] 32
$rand = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()
$rand.GetBytes($bytes)
$rand.Dispose()
$clientSecret = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)


$Title = "DemoProviderHostedApp"
$AppDomain = "whatever-you-want-here.azurewebsites.net"
$RedirectURI = "https://whatever-you-want-here.azurewebsites.net/demoproviderhostedapp/pages/default.aspx"
 
$appPrincipalId = $ClientId
$displayName = $Title
$servicePrincipalNames = @($ClientId, "$ClientId/$AppDomain") 
$addresses = New-MsolServicePrincipalAddresses -Address $RedirectURI -AddressType Reply 
 
New-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalNames $servicePrincipalNames -AppPrincipalId $appPrincipalId -DisplayName $displayName -AccountEnabled $true -Addresses $addresses -Type Password -Value $ClientSecret
 
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Sign -Value $clientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Symmetric -Usage Verify -Value $clientSecret
New-MsolServicePrincipalCredential -AppPrincipalId $clientId -Type Password -Usage Verify -Value $clientSecret

Write-Host "Client ID`t: $clientId`r`nClient Secret`t: $clientSecret"
```

However, there is not an equivalent of the server cmdlet Set-SPAppPrincipalPermission in SharePoint Online. A rough workaround is to build some scraper as shown on this [post](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2019/06/grant-permissions-and-trust-sharepoint.html), which explains a script that simulates click on a browser.

More reference:

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198664/how-to-generate-app-registration-data-in-sharepoint-online-through-powershell
- https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/5486

BR

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I understand correctly, two of my requirements cannot be met: SharePoint Online (must have) and run from Linux via the m365 cms line tool (should have).